# Expand one div to use remaining width when both divs have variable widths

Tags: css

I have two divs in which I cannot predict the width of each and has to be displayed inline.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">Primary variable content</div>
  <div id="right">variable content</div>
</div>
```

The CSS for this as of now:

```
  #left, #right{
    display:inline-block;
   }
```

I need

1. #right to be right aligned to the edge of the parent #container
2. #left to fill the remaining space.

Thus, all content of #right will be displayed and subsequently #left will have the remaining space to show its content. The overflow can be clipped.

I cannot use float:right here for this as it will not help achieve requirement 2. I *do not* know the widths of the content.

JS Fiddle of current situation here - http://jsfiddle.net/chandika/fVkzV/2/

Any ideas?

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fVkzV/3/)

Comment: That works! Wow, that was sitting right in front of my face and didn't realize!

Comment: The danger there is that the left div will wrap around the right div if it has more content, so you can add `overflow: hidden` to the left div to prevent that, as shown in my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy if you are able to reverse the order of the divs in the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
#container{
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 2px;
}
#left{
    border: 1px solid #99CC00;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#right{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #FFCC00
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="right">content, content</div>    
    <div id="left">some content here some content here some content here some content here some content here some content here some content here some content here some content here some content here some content here some content here some content here some content here some content here some content here some content here some content here some content here </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```